# if $2$ hyperbola are conjugates of each other then value of $c$

Tags: conic-sections

If the hyperbola $x^2+3xy+2y^2+2x+3y+2=0$ and $x^2+3xy+2y^2+2x+3y+c=0$ are conjugate of each other . Then $c$ equals

solution i try

Asymptotes of 1 st hyperbola is $x^2+3xy+2y^2+2x+3y+k=0$  and it represent $2$ pair of lines
so its discriminant is zero .so i am getting $k=1$
How to solve it from that point

Comment: Using the method in [this question and answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/182429/finding-the-conjugate-hyperbola), I get $c=2-2\frac{-\frac14}{-\frac14}=0$.